# cocoa : how to add semi transparent window over the main application window in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

[image][image]

Here the window is a semi transparent window and  i want to add this window to the main window when the application launches. 
but,this window is not adding over my semi transparent window on application launch

I want to achieve something like in x-code when you build your application.

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum you need a subclass of `NSWindow` so that you can construct it with `NSBorderlessWindowMask`.  This removes the frame entirely.

The simplest way to achieve the illusion of a custom window with a non-rectangular shape is to make the default "square" window completely invisible and perform custom rendering in an `NSView`.  Since `NSColor` has an alpha channel, sending `setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]` to the `NSWindow` is enough to erase it; also call `setOpaque:NO` to inform the window server that the window can show pixels that are behind it.

Your `NSView` subclass needs a `drawRect:` to render the rest.  A rounded-rectangle can be achieved using a path with 4 arcs.  A gray translucent background can be achieved in a similar way to the clear color; just use an alpha of (say) 0.65 along with the color value.

Comment: but i want to add this window when my application finished launching like in Xcode when you build your application ( see the image attached) and make this window to be visible over my application window. how can i do this?

Comment: i know how to create a semi transparent window but i don't know how to add this window over the application window when the application finished launching. Please help me

Comment: It could be the "level" of the window.  Try `[window setLevel:NSNormalWindowLevel]` on your transparent window so that it is placed in the same plane as document windows; then use `[window orderFront:nil]` to put the window in front of the other windows in its plane.